# BehaviorSubject is executed more than once

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

I am using angular 4 for my app and I use behaviorSubject to communicate between component, everythings were working fine

Here is my code:

```
export class Globals {
loadStudentsByClass: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject<string>(null);
}

export class ClassComponent implements OnInit {
selectNewClass() {
    console.log('About to select new class', this.selectedClass);
    this.globals.loadStudentsByClass.next(this.selectedClass); 
    this.globals.changeClassBehavior.next(true);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('');
  }
}

export class StudentComponent implements OnInit {
    this.globals.loadStudentsByClass.subscribe(value => {
          if (!isNullOrUndefined(value) && this.selectedClass !== value) {
            console.log('loadStudentsByClass=> home');
            this.loadStudentsByClass(this.selectedClass);
          }
        });
}
```

So, I have the component `ClassComponent` who triggers the `StudentComponent` to call the function `loadStudentsByClass`.

This is the only place where I call this behavior subject, but I find my behavior Subject emitted more than once

The problem is why behaviorSubject execute `loadStudentsByClass` more than once although `this.globals.loadStudentsByClass.next(this.selectedClass);` is called only one time

By the way the number of execution depends on the numbers of views I visited in the application

Comment: Can u provide some more code or better a demo code on stackblitz.com >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably forgot to unsubscribe in your StudentComponent when the components gets destroyed. Save the subscription in a class variable and in `ngOnDestroy()` lifecycle hook call `subscription.unsubscribe()`

Comment: I did it but still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

This will call twice, because whenever the behaviourSubject changes it will emit the latest values. Previously it was null (as default value) which you have given it and next when the service response came you are doing next so it will emit the latest value after change, which is fair enough. For your code you should only check for

```
if(value){// do the stuff here}
```

Comment: I know that it is called twice (first time is null and second time with value), the problem occurs after the second time when there is a value, with the same value, it can be called more than twice

Comment: Might there is some use case where you are leaving that page and coming again so it might get called, because the subscription you are making is still alive even you leave the page. To avoid that you should do something like below:

this.mySubscription = this.globals.loadStudentsByClass.subscribe(value => {
          if (!isNullOrUndefined(value) && this.selectedClass !== value) {
            console.log('loadStudentsByClass=> home');
            this.loadStudentsByClass(this.selectedClass);
          }
        });

ngOnDestroy(){this.mySubscription.unsubscribe();}

Comment: I noticed you mentioned By the way the number of execution depends on the numbers of views I visited in the application.

For sure you have to unsubscribe it to avoid the multiple subscriptions. This is what happening right now. This may result in memory leaks as well in future. Better to unsubscribe it on ngOnDestroy() life cycle hook of angular

Comment: I did so, I saved my subscription and then destroy it, but still have the same problem `ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }` .should I destroy all the component or only StudentComponent's subscription

Comment: You should destroy all the subscriptions wherever you are subscribing, once the component is not in memor; which is ngOnDestroy()

Comment: It works fine, thanks a lot, I  have only one question, is there a bad effect on using `unsubscribe()`

Comment: No, thing is whenever we do observable.next() so in this case we are explicitly making a subscription that we need to take care by using unsubscribe. Also you get the understanding of Observable.complete() where we can complete the observable. I am not sure about it in detail. But better to have a look and see for better options.

But yeah truly there is no harm in unsubscribing the subscriptions which we invoked. It definitely going to avoid memory leaks in production. It is the ideal way to handle it. But you can find and explore more options to do it in the best n best way :)

Answer (score 0):

Try a replay subject that has no initial value but will still cache your stream:

```
export class Globals {
loadStudentsByClass = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);
}
```